# CSV file is being created and headers are written but no data exports to the CSV after the headers

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

[image]
[image]

you guys have been awsesome in helping me get my project underway. I am running into an issue where I have built a gui to take invoice information and output it to a csv under certain headings. This CSV will then be imported into accounting software so its important that the data aligns with the proper headers. For some reason, i cannot get the data to actually write to the csv file. The way its supposed to work, is the user enters data, clicks Save to create the List, then Export to write it to the CSV. I was hoping that it would create successive rows each time the user exports new data, building more and more rows to import to the accounting software. The print commands show the lists are being created but I cannot get the data to write to the CSV. Any help is appreciated.

```
from csv import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

window=Tk()
window.title("Data Entry")
window.geometry("800x400")
main_list=[]

#Functions for Buttons
def Add():
   global data_list
   global main_list
   data_list=[vendor_ID.get(),
        description.get(),
        invoice_amount.get(),
        invoice_date.get(),
        due_date.get(),
        post_date.get(),
        dist_amount.get(),
        dist_account_num.get()
        ]
   main_list.append(data_list)
   messagebox.showinfo("Information","The data has been added successfully")
   print(data_list)
   print(main_list)

def Save():
   with open("InvoiceImport.csv", "w") as file:
      Writer = writer(file)
      Writer.writerow(["Vendor ID",
                       "Invoice Number",
                       "Description",
                       "Invoice Amount",
                       "Invoice Date,",
                       "Due Date",
                       "Post Date",
                       "Invoice Distribution Amount",
                       "Invoice Distribution Debit account number"
                       ])
      Writer.writerows(main_list)
      messagebox.showinfo("Information", "Saved succesfully")

def Clear():
   vendor_ID.delete(0,END)
   invoice_number.delete(0,END)
   description.delete(0,END)
   invoice_amount.delete(0, END)
   invoice_date.delete(0, END)
   due_date.delete(0, END)
   post_date.delete(0, END)
   dist_amount.delete(0, END)
   dist_account_num.delete(0, END)


#Frame Set Up
left_frame = Frame(window)
middle_frame= Frame(window)
right_frame = Frame(window)
bottom_frame = Frame(window)

#Label Setup
label1 = Label(left_frame, text="Vendor ID: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label2 = Label(left_frame, text="Invoice number: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label3 = Label(left_frame, text="Description: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label4 = Label(left_frame, text="Invoice Amount: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label5 = Label(left_frame, text="Invoice Date: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label6 = Label(middle_frame, text="Due date: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label7 = Label(middle_frame, text="Post date: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label8 = Label(middle_frame, text="Invoice Distribution Amount: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label9 = Label(middle_frame, text="Invoice Distribution Debit account number: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label10 = Label(middle_frame, text=" ",padx=20,pady=10)


label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
label3.grid(row=2, column=0)
label4.grid(row=3, column=0)
label5.grid(row=4, column=0)
label6.grid(row=0, column=0)
label7.grid(row=1, column=0)
label8.grid(row=2, column=0)
label9.grid(row=3, column=0)
label10.grid(row=4, column=0)


#Entry Fields
vendor_ID=Entry(left_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
invoice_number=Entry(left_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
description=Entry(left_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
invoice_amount=Entry(left_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
invoice_date=Entry(left_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
due_date=Entry(middle_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
post_date=Entry(middle_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
dist_amount=Entry(middle_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)
dist_account_num=Entry(middle_frame, width=30,borderwidth=3)

#Buttons
save=Button(bottom_frame, text="Save",padx=20,pady=10,command=Save)
add=Button(bottom_frame, text="Export",padx=20,pady=10,command=Add)
clear=Button(bottom_frame, text="Clear",padx=18,pady=10,command=Clear)
Exit=Button(bottom_frame, text="Exit",padx=20,pady=10,command=window.quit)

left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
middle_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=2)
bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

vendor_ID.grid(row=0,column=1)
invoice_number.grid(row=1,column=1)
description.grid(row=2,column=1)
invoice_amount.grid(row=3,column=1)
invoice_date.grid(row=4,column=1)
due_date.grid(row=0,column=1)
post_date.grid(row=1,column=1)
dist_amount.grid(row=2,column=1)
dist_account_num.grid(row=3,column=1)

save.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
add.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
clear.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2)
Exit.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly does happen when you click the "Save" button?  Does the messagebox show up?  Are you sure the file isn't just being written in an unexpected location?

Comment: When I click save, the message populates as expected, then the console outputs the lists with the data as you would expect. The headers get created in the file and I can see the file actually pop up in Explorer. When you open the file, the headers have been created but no actual data from the lists are showing.

Comment: Looking at the question again, you say you're clicking Save before Export - it is the latter Button, that calls `Add()`, that actually puts any data into `main_list`.  Clicking Save first would be expected to produce a file with headers only.  Perhaps your Buttons just require clearer names?

Comment: That is correct. Add button actually creates the list from data_list and then under the Export function, it appends main_list with data_list. main_list is then used in the   Writer.writerows(main_list) command to output to the csv

Comment: I've added screenshots showing that it creates the file but it doesnt actually write the main_list to the csv

Comment: Have you verified that `main_list` is non-empty when you write it to the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got **Save** button mixed up with **Export** button.
From my testing, the Save button creates a .csv file successfully, while Export button prints values into the console. According to your post Export should create a file and Save should prepare values.

The reason why your program generates empty .csv file is because you click Save first without preparing the contents first (by clicking Export).

Swap function calls of Save Button and Export Button.
It should look like this:

```
#Buttons
save=Button(bottom_frame, text="Save",padx=20,pady=10,command=Add)
add=Button(bottom_frame, text="Export",padx=20,pady=10,command=Save)
```

Comment: ........wow

I cant believe I did that....been working on this to long apparently. Thank you so much...any chance you can tell me how to get it to stop creating empty lines in the csv?

Comment: Actually, I think i got it with the newline command. Thank you so much! Sorry for all the confusion. I think Ive just been staring at this to long. Much Appreciated both of you for the help!